# A-Frame camera duplicates when delared through a-entity

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, aframe

I am using A-Frame with React for my project, and ran into an issue where camera is duplicated when declared through `a-entity`. `a-camera` only creates a single camera element as expected.

```
{/* Camera */}
<a-entity
  camera
  orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; initialPosition: -5 5 20" />
```

I am fairly certain the *extra* camera is the default camera generated by A-Frame if no camera has been declared. But the camera has been declared, and can been seen in the inspector. I have no issue with `a-camera` however.

[image]